# Should any or all of the NT appearances of the designation, "My God," be seen as intentional allusions to Hosea 2:23?

Tags: nt-use-of-hebrew-bible, hosea

There are many NT passages that use the phrase, "My God" (Mat 27:46
Mar 15:34;Jhn 20:17, 28;Rom 1:8;1Co 1:4;Phl 1:3;Phm 1:4;Rev 3:2, 12;Mat 5:11;Mat 26:28;Mar 10:40;Mar 14:24;Luk 1:47;Luk 13:33;Luk 22:19-20;Jhn 4:34;Jhn 5:24-25, 30;Jhn 6:38;Jhn 7:16-17;Jhn 8:42, 54;Act 2:17;Act 13:22, 33;Act 15:19;Act 20:24;Act 24:17;Rom 1:9;Rom 3:7;Rom 7:4, 7, 25;Rom 9:17, 25-26;Rom 10:1, 21;Rom 15:17-18, 30;Rom 16:25;1Co 7:17;1Co 9:17;1Co 11:24). To view the verses themselves, please [click here](https://www.blueletterbible.org/tools/MultiVerse.cfm?s=009dwI) and [here for the Greek](https://www.blueletterbible.org/tools/MultiVerse.cfm?s=009dzX).

Should any or all of these be seen as intentional allusions to this?:

> [Hos 2:23 YLT] (23) And I have sowed her to Me in the land, And I have pitied Lo-Ruhamah, And I have said to Lo-Ammi, My people thou art, and it saith, **My God!**'
>
> > [Hos 2:23 CCAT LXX] (23) καὶ σπερῶ αὐτὴν ἐμαυτῷ ἐπὶ τῆς γῆς καὶ ἐλεήσω τὴν Οὐκ-ἠλεημένην καὶ ἐρῶ τῷ Οὐ-λαῷ-μου λαός μου εἶ σύ καὶ αὐτὸς ἐρεῗ **κύριος ὁ θεός μου εἶ σύ**

Note: In my LXX, the CCAT LXX, it reads "Lord, you are my God".

Comment: Perhaps I am exceedingly dim - or getting dimmer in my old age - but I have not, yet, understood the point of the question. To what, are you suggesting, is there an allusion ?

Comment: Hi Nigel. I might restate/clarify the question like this... Hosea seems to be predicting that resurrected Israel - Jews that had fallen out of covenant with the LORD - would say "Lord, you are my God". Are any or all of these NT references consciously or unconsciously fulfilling that prophecy? Or is that prophecy orphaned and these NT mentions all just coincidence?

Comment: Maybe God is predicting that the entire nation has not (really) known him at all - not in Spirit. And maybe Hosea sees a time in the future when another (kind) of people will know God in a superior (kind of) way.

Comment: For more background, please refer to my answer on a related Hosea question, here: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/28832/does-hosea-refer-to-gentiles-also-as-quoted-by-paul-in-romans-925/29342#29342

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression (referring to the LORD, YHWH) is common in the OT:

- Ex 15:2, The LORD is my strength and my song, and He has become my salvation. He is **my God**, and I will praise Him, my father’s God, and I will exalt Him.
- 1 chron 29:3, Moreover, because of my delight in the house of **my God**, I now give for it my personal treasures of gold and silver, over and above all that I have provided for this holy temple:
- Ezra 9:6, saying: “O **my God**, I am ashamed and blush to lift my face to you, **my God**, for our iniquities have risen higher than our heads, and our guilt has mounted up to the heavens.
- Neh 13:14, Remember me for this, O **my God**, and do not blot out my deeds of loving devotion for the house of **my God** and for its services.
- Ps 15:1, **My God, my God**, why have you forsaken me? Why are you so far from saving me, so far from my cries of anguish?
- Ps 42:11, Why are you downcast, O my soul? Why the unease within me? Put your hope in God, for I will yet praise Him, my Savior and **my God**.
- Ps 43:4, 5, Then I will go to the altar of God, to God, my greatest joy. I will praise You with the harp, O God, **my God**.Why are you downcast, O my soul? Why the unease within me? Put your hope in God, for I will yet praise Him, my Savior and **my God**.
- Ps 59:10, My God of loving devotion will come to meet me; God will let me stare down my foes.
- Ps 63:1, You, God, are **my God**, earnestly I seek you; I thirst for you, my whole being longs for you, in a dry and parched land where there is no water.
- Ps 68:24, They have seen Your procession, O God—the march of **my God** and King into the sanctuary.
- Ps 118:28, You are **my God**, and I will give You thanks. You are **my God**, and I will exalt You.
- Micah 7:7, But as for me, I will look to the LORD; I will wait for the God of my salvation. **My God** will hear me.
- Hab 1:12, Are You not from everlasting, O LORD, **my God**, my Holy One? We will not die. O LORD, You have appointed them to execute judgment; O Rock, You have established them for correction.

… and so forth - there are many more.

The point is this, in every instance of this occurring, "my God" (referring to the LORD) is spoken by a devoted follower of the LORD.  This is the distinguishing characteristic of God's faithful people - they can call Him, "my God" in contradistinction to serving any of the numerous false gods.

The reverse also occurs:  God often visits people and says something like, "I am the God of Abraham, Isaac and Israel, … ".  That is, these people (Abraham, Isaac and Israel) called my "my God" and therefore, did not serve false gods.

In the time of Hosea's prophecy, many people were turning away from the LORD until the LORD rejected the northern kingdom and it went into Assyrian captivity.

The same problem would occur with the southern kingdom of Judah that caused Jesus to lament: "O Jerusalem, Jerusalem, who kills the prophets and stones those sent to her, how often I have longed to gather your children together, as a hen gathers her chicks under her wings, but you were unwilling! Look, your house is left to you desolate."  Here Jesus predicts that a short time later, the Jews would be rejected and the Gospel went to the gentiles instead.

Hosea 2:23 predicts the same thing:

> And I will sow her as My own in the land, and I will have compassion
> on ‘No Compassion.’  I will say to those called ‘Not My People,’ ‘You
> are My people,’ and they will say, ‘You are my God.’”

This text is interpreted by Peter and Paul in Rom 9:25 and 1 Peter 2:10 in support of the same idea.  Christians now call the LORD, "My God" along with anyone else who makes such a truthful claim, compose the people of God.